# Can i resize Msgbox ? and isert image on it?

Tags: vbscript

How to Enlarge msgbox on VBS?

Already tried below and it display the standard size.

```
MsgBox "This is a sample box", vbExclamation
```

Expect size is half or 1/4 of the screen to be covered by the msgbox

Comment: this is my Current Code.
MsgBox "This is a sample box", vbExclamation

Comment: You can't do any of that with the built-in `MsgBox` but you could build a custom dialog using `InternetExplorer.Application` or a [tag:hta].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't.

MsgBox has the following parameters

> MsgBox (prompt, [ buttons, ] [ title, ] [ helpfile, context ])
>   ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/msgbox-function))

But it does grow with to accommodate the text passed as `prompt`. So if you pass a large text it will be bigger.

Images except for the ones show for things like `vbExclamation` are not possible either.